# How to run R code written under windows in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, r, correlation

Due to the big size of the data (10 GB),I have to run it using the server of our unit(to avoid memory issues).I can use the server only if my platform is Linux . I am grateful to any idea on how we can run this code under Linux platform.

```
dir1 <- list.files("D:sdr", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
dir2 <- list.files("D:dsa", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
file_tot<-array(dim=c(1440,720,664,2))
for(i in 1:length(dir1)){
file_tot[,,i,2] <- file_tot[,,i,2]*0.000030518594759971
file_tot[,,i,2][file_tot[,,i,2] ==  9999 ] <- NA 
                      }
 })
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to learn Linux a little bit first... It probably is time to install it on your laptop for learning purposes...

Comment: the only problem is your use of absolute path names starting with `D:`, which will be practically unreplicable on Linux.

Comment: @Ben Bolker ,if it is only the path,then there is no problem because he can load the data to his computer and will change the directory!!.

Comment: You may also need to translate line breaks in the source code to use the Unix convention oF LF.

Comment: as far as I can see, if you can successfully list the files then everything else should work in a platform-independent way.  In any case it would seem prudent to run a test on a small subset of the data and check that the results are consistent ...

Comment: Ben Bolker:how we list the data?you meant we use the code as it is after listing the files?

Comment: I mean that the first two lines of the code are the ones that seem problematic, because they use an absolute file location that is unlikely to exist on a Linux system.  If you can get through this part, i.e. you can get `dir1` and `dir2` to contain vectors of the names of the files you need to read in, then you should be OK.

Comment: By the way, it's possible that the computational results will differ *very* slightly (i.e. at the level of numeric fuzz, say less than a tolerance of 10^(-6) or so) on different platforms/architectures/etc.. This is more or less unavoidable if you're doing floating-point (as opposed to integer) calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of us have been writing code for Windows and Linux (and OS X ...) for years.  Construct yourself little helper functions

```
isLinux <- function() unname(Sys.info()["sysname"]) == "Linux"
```

and likewise for Windows.  Then construct your path programmatically:

```
ourRootDir <- function() ifelse( isLinux(), "/opt/data/someThing", "D:/data")
```

via

```
datapath <- file.path( ourRootDir(), "project", "some", "where")
```

and afterwards *all actual analysis commands will most likely be portable without change*.

Among the 4200+ CRAN package, very few do not exist on all platforms.

Also, data written via `save()` on one system *can be loaded on another* and as this is a binary format with compression, you also save a lot of time.

Comment: I am a bit confused.so I run those commands on windows and then i add the path to connect to the server as Linux or these are for Linux. could you please add little description.

Comment: Everything on the right of `function()` is a base R command, use the R help to read up and learn about them.

Comment: This is for both datasets  dir1 and dir2 ?? I see only D:/data.what some ,project , where stand for?

Comment: Read  the help. It is not that hard. Modify my `ourRootDir()` to give you the Linux and Windows path, respectively. Stick that in into your `list.files()` call.  If none of this is comprehensible to you, hire a consultant.